# Run-time error "6":overflow

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with this code.

```
Dim arr(33002 To 33015) As Variant
Dim clicks As Integer
Sub SRT_L_ZTH()
    If arr(33002) = "" Then
        For i = 33002 To 33015
            arr(i) = i
        Next i

        Call Shuffle(arr)

        Range("C24").Value = arr(33002)
        Range("C25").Value = arr(33003)
        clicks = 33004
    Else
         Range("C24").Value = arr(clicks)
        Range("C25").Value = arr(clicks + 1)
        clicks = clicks + 2
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, J As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, Temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For i = Low To Hi
        Helper(i) = Rnd
    Next i


    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

The part I am having trouble with is the line 
    "clicks = 33004"

I did not develop this code and the person who did no longer works with me. I have very little understanding of VBA so please, if you can help, try to keep your explanation very basic.

Thanks!

Comment: `Dim clicks As Long`

Comment: Try changing clicks to `Dim clicks As Long`

Comment: And the "explanation" is that the maximum number that can be stored in an `Integer` variable is `32767`.